# Chinese character handling in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to search a document which contains Chinese characters. Indexes enabled are word searches, 3 character search, fast phrase search. Before re-indexing code gives correct results but after re-indexing its not giving expected output.

XML:

```
<root>
  <name xml:lang="en">Propylene</name>
  <name xml:lang="zh">丙烯</name>
</root>
```

Search Query:

```
cts:search(collection('live'),
  cts:element-query(xs:QName('name'), 
    cts:word-query('丙烯', ("wildcarded", "whitespace-insensitive", "lang=zh"), 1)))
```

I expect the above XML in the result set but it's not in the result set after re-indexing.

Is indexing different for other languages than "English" in MarkLogic?

Comment: Works just fine at my end, but I am using 9.0-7. Can you run a test with latest patch release if you are not running latest yet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Working fine in 9.0-5 as well. But the version i have on my environment is 8.0-5. I am not able to understand the difference in behavior between the two versions for language support for Chinese characters.

Comment: It looks like there have been a number of language related bugfixes in the 9 release. That is probably why. You could try upgrading to latest patch release of ML8 (currently 8.0-9.1), but you might have to upgrade to ML9..

Answer (score 0):

Note the following regarding languages in v9:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap3#id_28687

https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/484/0/marklogic-server-v9-tokenization-and-stemming